# How to find the most similar commit to a modified file?

Tags: git, diff, similarity

I recently received a modification of a file of mine that I put under revision control, but I cannot spot on which commit this modified file is based.

So, is there a way to determine which commit modifying a given file is the least different to an edited version?

Comment: related: [Git: How can I find a commit that most closely matches a directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6388283/321973)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any magical way of checking this but you might want to try this:

```
git diff --stat HEAD..HEAD~10 -- myfile.cpp
```

and manually change the HEAD~10

It will tell you how many difference there are between the revisions.

You can automate this using:

```
for i in {1..5}; do echo "HEAD~$i"; git diff --stat HEAD~$i..HEAD CMakeLists.txt ; done
```

Comment: thanks, I can pipe the output of `git-diff --stat` to `grep myfile.cpp | gawk ' { print $3 } '` to reduce that to the amount of changes. I guess together with that for loop one can then use `sort` to obtain the best candidates and review their diffs manually

Comment: instead of that for loop, you can use `git log --stat myfile.cpp`, and again with some smart `gawk`ing the output might be formatted into something like "commitid howManyChanges" ( I don't know enough about `awk` though)

Comment: `git log --numstat --oneline -- myfile.cpp` gives a nice and brief output (ok, enough comments added...)