# How can I know which commit was used when installing a pip package from git?

Tags: python, git, pip

If I install a package from git using https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git
does the specific commit that was checked out logged somewhere?

Comment: What does `pip freeze` show?

Comment: the version from setup.py, which isn't specific enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [knittl's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6388694/190597) to find the nearest commit -- the only modification below is to address the fact that you are comparing the git tree to an installed package, not a git repository:

Since the installed package may lack some of the directory structure of the git
repository, make a new directory for the git repo. I'll use `html5lib` for an example:

```
mkdir ~/tmp/html5lib
cd ~/tmp/html5lib/
git init
```

Now fetch the git tree:

```
git remote add foreign https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python
git fetch foreign
```

Copy the installed package into the git repo:

```
rsync -a ~/.virtualenvs/muffy/lib/python3.4/site-packages/html5lib ~/tmp/html5lib/
```

Run `git diff` to compare the current state of the repo (with the installed package's code) to each revision in the git tree:

```
for REV in $(git rev-list --all); do
    echo $(git diff --shortstat foreign/master $REV) $REV ;
done | sort -n
```

This sorts by the number of files changed, then the number of insertions, then deletions.
The output will look something like this:

```
1 file changed, 3 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-) 17499b9763a090f7715af49555d21fe4b558958b
2 files changed, 10 insertions(+), 8 deletions(-) ec674a97243e76da43f06abfd0a891308f1ff801
3 files changed, 17 insertions(+), 12 deletions(-) 1a28d721091a2c433c6e8471d14cbb75afd70d1c
4 files changed, 18 insertions(+), 13 deletions(-) ff6111cd82191a2eb963d6d662c6da8fa2e7ddde
6 files changed, 19 insertions(+), 19 deletions(-) ea0fafdbff732b1272140b696d6948054ed1d6d2
```

The last item on each line is the associated git commit.

If the git history is very long you'll want to modify `git rev-list --all` to a range of commits. For example, use `git rev-list tag1..tag2` to search between two tags. If you know approximately when the package was installed, you might have a good guess for what tags to use. Use `git tag` to show the names of the possible tags.
See [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) for more options.

Answer (score 2):

One possible alternative is to use `pip install --editable`. In such case `pip` will clone the repo to `$PREFIX/src/$egg_name` (where `$PREFIX` is either your virtualenv directory or current working directory), and then just create and `egg-link` pointing to that path. This way, you will easily be able to check current revision for the cloned repo.

On the other hand, package installed this way might have different file structure than the one installed in a regularl way. So in some cases this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

It is not. If you just want to know — lookup the commit at the head of the installed branch. If you want to install a specific commit — name the commit. For example:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/sqlobject/sqlobject.git@623a5802#egg=sqlobject
```

Comment: I want to know the commit of a module that was already installed, and more commits were added to the branch since then

Comment: Then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I can easily find the commit hash for a package of mine.

I've used [Cookie Cutter](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter) tool to generate my python package structure. When I install my package from a GitLab repository, a directory named `<package-name>-<version>.dist-info` is generated inside my Python `Lib` directory.

There's a file `direct_url.json` that records the commit_id of the repository:
[image: Install info]

This file is a [standard file in Python packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/direct-url/) as posted in the comments.

Comment: [Recording the Direct URL Origin of installed distributions — Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/direct-url/)