# Comparing two files in linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, diff, file-comparison

There are two files called **"a.txt"** and **"b.txt"** both have a list of words. Now I want to check which words are extra in **"a.txt"** and  are not in **"b.txt"**.

I need a efficient algorithm as I need to compare two dictionaries.

Comment: `diff a.txt b.txt` is not enough?

Comment: Can the words occur several times in each file? Can you sort the files?

Comment: i need only those words that are no present in "b.txt" and are present in a.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution for this :

```
mkdir temp
mkdir results
cp /usr/share/dict/american-english ~/temp/american-english-dictionary
cp /usr/share/dict/british-english ~/temp/british-english-dictionary
cat ~/temp/american-english-dictionary | wc -l > ~/results/count-american-english-dictionary
cat ~/temp/british-english-dictionary | wc -l > ~/results/count-british-english-dictionary
grep -Fxf ~/temp/american-english-dictionary ~/temp/british-english-dictionary > ~/results/common-english
grep -Fxvf ~/results/common-english ~/temp/american-english-dictionary > ~/results/unique-american-english
grep -Fxvf ~/results/common-english ~/temp/british-english-dictionary > ~/results/unique-british-english
```

Comment: Did you try any of the other solutions? Did one of these solutions was useful to you? Your question is generic enough to draw in many users, but your answer is more specific for my taste... For my particular case `sdiff -s file1 file2` was useful.

Comment: @Metafaniel my solution do not use sdiff command. It only use linux built in commands to solve the problem.

Answer (score 406):

if you have vim installed,try this:

```
vimdiff file1 file2
```

or

```
vim -d file1 file2
```

you will find it fantastic.[image]

Comment: Your answer is awesome, but my teacher required me to not use any library function :P

Comment: The codes colored means they are different in two files. @zygimantus

Comment: This solution is awesome, it's just a pity that is vim because it sometimes unnecessary complex.

Comment: How to exit `vimdiff file1 file2` ?

Comment: press ESC then press column and q like this ":q"

Answer (score 83):

Sort them and use `comm`:

```
comm -23 <(sort a.txt) <(sort b.txt)
```

`comm` compares (sorted) input files and by default outputs three columns: lines that are unique to a, lines that are unique to b, and lines that are present in both. By specifying `-1`, `-2` and/or `-3` you can suppress the corresponding output. Therefore `comm -23 a b` lists only the entries that are unique to a. I use the `<(...)` syntax to sort the files on the fly, if they are already sorted you don't need this.

Comment: I have added my own answer using only grep commands, please tell me is  it more efficient?

Comment: @AliImran, `comm` is more efficient because it does the job in a single run, without storing the entire file in memory. Since you're using dictionaries that are most likely already sorted you don't even need to `sort` them. Using `grep -f file1 file2` on the other hand will load the entire `file1` into memory and compare each line in `file2` with all of those entries, which is much less efficient. It's mostly useful for small, unsorted `-f file1`.

Comment: Thanks @AndersJohansson for sharing the "comm" command. Its nifty indeed. I frequently have to do outer joins between files and this does the trick.

Comment: Pay attention to the new line character... I just found that `\n` will also be included to do comparing.

Answer (score 48):

If you prefer the diff output style from `git diff`, you can use it with the `--no-index` flag to compare files not in a git repository:

```
git diff --no-index a.txt b.txt
```

Using a couple of files with around 200k file name strings in each, I benchmarked (with the built-in `time`command) this approach vs some of the other answers here:

```sh
git diff --no-index a.txt b.txt
# ~1.2s

comm -23 <(sort a.txt) <(sort b.txt)
# ~0.2s

diff a.txt b.txt
# ~2.6s

sdiff a.txt b.txt
# ~2.7s

vimdiff a.txt b.txt
# ~3.2s
```

`comm` seems to be the fastest by far, while `git diff --no-index` appears to be the fastest approach for diff-style output.

---

**Update 2018-03-25** You can actually omit the `--no-index` flag unless you are inside a git repository and want to compare untracked files within that repository. From [the man pages](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html):

> This form is to compare the given two paths on the filesystem. You can omit the --no-index option when running the command in a working tree controlled by Git and at least one of the paths points outside the working tree, or when running the command outside a working tree controlled by Git.

Answer (score 37):

Try `sdiff` (`man sdiff`)

```
sdiff -s file1 file2
```

Answer (score 34):

You can use `diff` tool in linux to compare two files. You can use **--changed-group-format** and **--unchanged-group-format** options to filter required data.

Following three options can use to select the relevant group for each option:

- '%<'      get lines from FILE1
- '%>'   get lines from FILE2
- ''    (empty string) for removing lines from both files.

> E.g: **diff --changed-group-format="%<" --unchanged-group-format=""  file1.txt file2.txt**

```
[root@vmoracle11 tmp]# cat file1.txt 
test one
test two
test three
test four
test eight
[root@vmoracle11 tmp]# cat file2.txt 
test one
test three
test nine
[root@vmoracle11 tmp]# diff --changed-group-format='%<' --unchanged-group-format='' file1.txt file2.txt 
test two
test four
test eight
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also use: **colordiff**: Displays the output of diff with colors.

About **vimdiff**: It allows you to compare files via SSH, for example :

```
vimdiff /var/log/secure scp://192.168.1.25/var/log/secure
```

Extracted from: http://www.sysadmit.com/2016/05/linux-diferencias-entre-dos-archivos.html

Answer (score 8):

Also, do not forget about [mcdiff](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-mcdiff/) - Internal diff viewer of [GNU Midnight Commander](https://midnight-commander.org/).

For example:

```
mcdiff file1 file2
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

Use `comm -13` *(requires sorted files)*:

```
$ cat file1
one
two
three

$ cat file2
one
two
three
four

$ comm -13 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
four
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use:

```
sdiff file1 file2
```

To display differences side by side within your terminal!

Answer (score 2):

```
diff a.txt b.txt | grep '<'
```

can then pipe to cut for a clean output

```
diff a.txt b.txt | grep '<' | cut -c 3
```

Answer (score -1):

Using awk for it. Test files:

```
$ cat a.txt
one
two
three
four
four
$ cat b.txt
three
two
one
```

The awk:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                    # process b.txt  or the first file
    seen[$0]                 # hash words to hash seen
    next                     # next word in b.txt
}                            # process a.txt  or all files after the first
!($0 in seen)' b.txt a.txt   # if word is not hashed to seen, output it
```

Duplicates are outputed:

```
four
four
```

To avoid duplicates, add each newly met word in a.txt to `seen` hash:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {
    seen[$0]
    next
}
!($0 in seen) {              # if word is not hashed to seen
    seen[$0]                 # hash unseen a.txt words to seen to avoid duplicates 
    print                    # and output it
}' b.txt a.txt
```

Output:

```
four
```

If the word lists are comma-separated, like:

```
$ cat a.txt
four,four,three,three,two,one
five,six
$ cat b.txt
one,two,three
```

you have to do a couple of extra laps (`for`loops):

```
awk -F, '                    # comma-separated input
NR==FNR {
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)       # loop all comma-separated fields
        seen[$i]
    next
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if(!($i in seen)) {
             seen[$i]        # this time we buffer output (below):
             buffer=buffer (buffer==""?"":",") $i
        }
    if(buffer!="") {         # output unempty buffers after each record in a.txt
        print buffer
        buffer=""
    }
}' b.txt a.txt
```

Output this time:

```
four
five,six
```