# bash compare the contents of two files and based on the results do two different actions

Tags: bash, diff, cmp, comm

Cannot use **diff** and cannot use **cmp**.

We are able to use **comm** with success, but I am not getting the correct results when used with a conditional in script.

```
#!/bin/bash
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/14500821/175063

comm -23 <(sort /home/folder/old.txt) <(sort /home/folder/new.txt)
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
   echo "There are no changes in the files"
else
   echo "New files were found. Return code was $?"
fi
```

It always returns:

> There are no changes in the files

as the comm command, runs successfully but the contents of the files are different.

I am very limited as to what can be added to this server as it is a corporate LINUX box.

Comment: `comm` always return 0 even on failure such as file not found. You need to check stdout to see if `comm` has output.

Comment: What do the files look like? You know that `$?` is the exit status of the last process and not the number of lines?

Comment: Ditto on `$?`.  Also, `comm -23` returns line in old.txt that are not in new.txt.  Lines in new.txt that are not in old.txt are ignored.    Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes comm -23 will show the difference with the name of the files.  I am pretty sure the exit code is not what is needed in this example.  I want to look for if there is a difference in the content of the files in the folder to alert me, otherwise wait until the next time the script runs.

Comment: Can you use `awk`?

Comment: _"Yes comm -23 will show the difference with the name of the files."_  No, it doesn't, not like `diff` or `cmp` anyway.  It shows output _only if_ there are lines in old that are not in new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
! comm -3 <(sort /home/folder/old.txt) <(sort /home/folder/new.txt) | grep -q '.*'
```

The `comm` command will succeed (exit with status 0) whether it finds any differences or not, but `grep` only succeeds if it finds a match. `-q` prevents grep from printing the match(es), and the pattern `'.*'` matches *anything*. Thus, `grep -q '.?'` succeeds if its input is nonempty. But you wanted success if there was a match, so I added the `!` at the beginning to invert the status.

I also made one other change: `comm -23` will print lines that're in the first file (old.txt) and not in the second one (new.txt), but it will not print lines that're in the second but not the first. `comm -3` will print all lines that're unique to one of the files, so it'll find lines that've been removed *or* added between the two files.

BTW, testing whether `$?` is zero is unnecessary; just use the command directly as the `if` condition:

```
if ! comm -3 <(sort /home/folder/old.txt) <(sort /home/folder/new.txt) | grep -q '.*'; then
   echo "There are no changes in the files"
else
   echo "New files were found. Return code was $?"
fi
```

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the output of `comm` to `wc -l` to see if there were any new files found.

```
new_file_count=$(comm -13 <(sort /home/folder/old.txt) <(sort /home/folder/new.txt) | wc -l)
if [ $new_file_count -eq 0];then
   echo "There are no changes in the files"
else
   echo "New files were found. Count is $new_file_count"
fi
```

I changed the `comm` command to use `-13` so it will print the new files, since that's what your message suggests you want.

Comment: Not count.  The files are updated from a vendor.  Like file 101.dat would be updated to 102.dat and file 101.dat would be deleted.  We want to know if file 102.dat in this example we would then be notified.

Comment: This counts the number of lines that are in `new.txt` that aren't in `old.txt`. So the count will be `1` because `102.dat` is in the new file, but not in the old one.

Comment: Deleted lines are not counted, they would be counted by `comm -23`.