# Linux Join - command not listing appropriate output

Tags: linux, unix, rhel5

I have one file that has list of Ids like

File1.csv

```
123456
1234234
2324324
325435345
```

and other file structure is like this:

File2.csv

```
  1234234,asadasdas!w2eaesfd+smakdnjads,"points-ka"
  2131231,sadfasfa990-0;;'.sadsadsada,"points-ka"
  2324324,asadasdas!w2eaesfd+smasdasdfadewe,"points-ka"
  5434234234,adasdfsfhguse38873h78hu8i8377&*&*,"points-ka"
```

Now, I want to join the files using this command

join -t, file1.csv file2.csv

but this is not returning any output where am I going wrong?

Required Output:

```
 1234234,asadasdas!w2eaesfd+smakdnjads,"points-ka"
 2324324,asadasdas!w2eaesfd+smasdasdfadewe,"points-ka"
```

Comment: What if `join -t, <(sort file1.csv) <(sort file2.csv)`?

Comment: can I do it using grep ??

Answer (score 1):

The files have to be sorted on the join key before join will work.

```
sort file1.csv > file1sorted.csv
sort file2.csv > file2sorted.csv
join -t, f1s.csv f2s.csv

1234234,asadasdas!w2eaesfd+smakdnjads,"points-ka"
2324324,asadasdas!w2eaesfd+smasdasdfadewe,"points-ka"
```

Answer (score 0):

A requisite of join is that the files should be sorted first.

```
$ sort File1.csv > File1.sorted.csv

$ sort File2.csv > File2.sorted.csv

$ join -t, File1.sorted.csv File2.sorted.csv
1234234,asadasdas!w2eaesfd+smakdnjads,"points-ka"
2324324,asadasdas!w2eaesfd+smasdasdfadewe,"points-ka"
```

Comment: sort won't work here because one file is of 25 GB - so, running out of memory ... can you provide any other alternatives?

Comment: Does this help you in any way?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544709/compare-two-files-line-by-line-and-generate-the-difference-in-another-file