# Difference between two files without sorting

Tags: bash, shell, diff, difference, comm

I have the files `file1` and `file2`, where `file2` is a subset of `file1`. That means, if I iterate over `file1`, there are some lines that are in `file2`, and some that aren't, but there is no line in `file2` that is not in `file1`. There may be several lines with the same content in a file. Now I want to get the difference between them, that is, all lines of `file1` that aren't in `file2`.

According to [this well received answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544709/compare-two-files-line-by-line-and-generate-the-difference-in-another-file)

> diff(1) isn't the answer, comm(1) is.

(For whatever reason)

But as I understand, for `comm` the files need to be sorted first. The problem: Both files are ordered (not sorted!), and this order needs to be kept. So what I really want is to iterate over `file1`, and check for every line, if it is also in `file2`. If not, write it to `file3`. If the same content occurs more than once, it should be kept more than once!

Is there any way to do this with the command line?

Answer (score 5):

Try this with GNU grep:

```
grep -vFf file2 file1 > file3
```

**Update**:

```
grep -vxFf file2 file1 > file3
```

Comment: Looks good after looking at the first lines. I can't really say for sure (file is way too long), but I assume that's the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm ok I just compared the line numbers. It should be 5213, but it is 5211. Very small difference, but not entirely working, unfortunately.

Comment: Please upload file1 and file2 somewhere.

Comment: Perhaps file2 has `short line` and file1 has `short line with more text` and `short line`.

Comment: @WalterA: Thank you. I've updated my answer to avoid this substring problem.

Comment: Another difference may be repeated lines in file1 (lines a b a versus lines a b: Should the second line a be considered as difference?).

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not want to sort for avoiding temp files. This is possible with process substitution:

```
diff <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
# or
comm <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Edit: Using https://stackoverflow.com/a/4544925/3220113 I found another alternative (for text files with short lines):

```
diff -a --suppress-common-lines -y file2 file1 | sed 's/\s*>.//'
```

Comment: I don't want to sort because I want to keep the order.

Comment: I added an alternative without sorting