# diff on columns of two files in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file, diff

I want to do a very simple thing. I have two files as follows:

```
FILE 1:
A s1 p1
B s2 p2
C s3 p3

FILE2:
B s4 p4
A s1 p1
C s6 p6
```

I want to extract first and third column from both file and print diff of that file. One easy way is to create intermediate files with cut -f1,3 of both files and do diff. Thats what exactly i want my output is. But i don't want to create intermediate file. Any simple one liner to do that.

One more thing, both the files are NOT sorted, so unable to use join directly.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
diff <(cut -f1,3 file1) <(cut -f1,3 file2)
```

References:

[Compare two files line by line and generate the difference in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544709/compare-two-files-line-by-line-and-generate-the-difference-in-another-file)

Comment: yep, it's called process substitution in bash, as sjsam posted; in fish shell you use `psub`: `diff (cut -f1,3 file1 | psub) (cut -f1,3 file2 | psub)` (and you don't have `>(...)` yet)

Comment: Additionally, I had to specify the delimiter. So, `diff <(cut -d " " -f1,3 file1.txt) <(cut -d " " -f1,3  file2)`

Answer (score 4):

Use [[ process substitution ]](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)

```
diff -y <( awk '{print $1,$3}' file1) <( awk '{print $1,$3}' file2 )
```

should do it. Note `-y` option with `diff` is for side-by-side o/p.