# Compare two files and append the differences at the end

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I would like to compare two files, say `file1` and `file2`, and output two new files, say `file1.out` and `file2.out`, with the lines that are in common (according to `diff file1 file2`) occurring first, and then the lines in `file1` that are not in `file2` appended at the end of `file1.out`, and the lines in `file2` but not in `file1` appended at the end of `file2.out`.

For example, let's say I have `file1`:

```
A
B
C
E
```

and `file2`:

```
A
C
D
E
```

I would like to common lines, `A`, `C`, and `E` to come first in modified files `file1.out` and `file2.out`, in their original order, and the distinct lines, `B` and `D` respectively, to be moved to the end. With my example, that would yield `file1.out`:

```
A
C
E
B
```

and `file2.out`:

```
A
C
E
D
```

More generally, my input files might have thousands of lines that are mostly the same, with some scattered differences that I would like pushed at the end for easier visual inspection.

I have looked at related-type queries such as here ([Compare two files line by line and generate the difference in another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544709/compare-two-files-line-by-line-and-generate-the-difference-in-another-file)) but I did not find the solution I am looking for here. If you know how to generate output as described above, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Um, generate the `diff` to a temporary file, then `cat` that to append to the new file? Sadly you probably shouldn't try to append the output of `cat` directly to the file, as it might pick up the new content. You might instead diff to a variable and then echo the variable to append, if the diff is not too big. Bash will then do the temporary files for you.

Comment: Thanks, would it be possible for you to provide sample code (using my inputs) of what you said? I am really not an expert in bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can solve this problem by using `diff -U <large number>`. This will give you output that will be easy to parse to reconstruct what you want. If `<large number>` is larger than the longer of your two files, then you will get a predictable output format:

```
$diff -u 1000 file1 file2
--- file1       2019-07-22 14:39:39.344674000 -0400
+++ file2       2019-07-22 14:39:45.072654000 -0400
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
 A
+B
 C
-D
 E
```

Then you can use grep and sed to reconstruct the two output files you want:

```
diff -u 1000 file1 file2 | sed '1,3d' > tmp
grep '^ ' tmp | sed 's/^ //' > file1.out
cp file1.out file2.out
grep '^-' tmp | sed 's/^-//' >> file1.out
grep '^+' tmp | sed 's/^+//' >> file2.out
```

Notes:

- `sed '1,3d'` just deletes the first three lines of the diff output, since they're not contents. I previously had `tail +3` here but that is not so portable; sed is safer.
- The first grep extracts lines in common (start with a space in the diff).
- The next two greps extract lines not in common (`-` means in `file1` only, `+` in `file2` only).
- If `file1` and `file2` are identical, this will yield empty output files.

Comment: Somehow, I am getting the error 'head: cannot open '+3' for reading: No such file or directory' while trying diff -U 1000 file1 file2 | head +3' command. However, I could see though the output without using the 'head +3' like you showed above.

Comment: I guess it's a matter of versions of `tail`. I think GNU tail supports the `+3` syntax. The point is just to delete the first three lines of the diff, since they're not actual contents.

Comment: You can use `sed '1,3d'` to delete the first three lines of a file, instead of `tail +3`. I'll edit my answer.